# Node.JS Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080 in Ubuntu 14.0.4

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

i have error Node.JS Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080 in Ubuntu 14.0.4

before restart server all is good. but after restart i have problem.

my File:

```
var http = require('http');
var port = 8080;
var s = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
});

s.listen(port);

console.log("Listening on http://127.0.0.1:" + port + "/");
```

error:

```
root@euve249385:/var/www/websocket_proxy# node test1.js
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8080/
events.js:163
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1073:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1263:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1304:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1402:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/websocket_proxy/test1.js:16:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
root@euve24935:/var/www/websocket_proxy# Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080
-bash: Error:: command not found
```

Comment: Means some other process is running in port 8080

Comment: how to change port , and how to kill process 8080 for use with my app

Comment: Find your previous process and call kill on it. ```ps -ef``` will show all running processes. Look by path for you program. Then ```kill pid```. If this will not clear the socket, it might happen, but usually not, you will need to go deeper and reboot or release socket manually through another commands.